# How to locale a bug from panic

Tags: linux, usb, kernel, driver, panic

all.
I'm a kernel newbie. I want to know how to get useful infomations from painc such as which line or which function is wrong.
For example, following is a `panic-output` about `usb hiddev`, how to read it?  Thanks.

---

```
 BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 0000000000000028
IP: [<ffffffff813b4aa1>] free_async+0xa1/0x100
PGD 2326c9067 PUD 230f4c067 PMD 0 
Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP 
last sysfs file: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.2/usb8/8-2/speed
CPU 3 
Modules linked in: ebtable_nat ebtables ipt_MASQUERADE iptable_nat nf_nat xt_CHECKSUM iptable_mangle bridge stp l]

Pid: 2400, comm: lsusb Tainted: G          I---------------    2.6.32-296.el664fixes.3.x86_64 #1 Dell Inc. OptiPlN
RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff813b4aa1>]  do_IRQ: 0.97 No irq handler for vector (irq -1)
[Firmware Bug]: the BIOS has corrupted hw-PMU resources (MSR 186 is 53003c)
�Mounting proc filesystem
Mounting sysfs filesystem
Creating /dev
Creating initial device nodes
setfont: KDFONTOP: Invalid argument
Free memory/Total memory (free %): 78672 / 114884 ( 68.4795 )
Loading dm-mod.ko module
Loading dm-log.ko module
Loading dm-region-hash.ko module
Loading dm-mirror.ko module
Loading dm-zero.ko module
Loading dm-snapshot.ko module
Loading freq_table.ko module
Loading mperf.ko module
Loading ipt_REJECT.ko module
Loading nf_defrag_ipv4.ko module
Loading ip_tables.ko module
Loading nf_conntrack.ko module
Loading ip6_tables.ko module
Loading ipv6.ko module
Loading fat.ko module
Loading macvlan.ko module
Loading tun.ko module
Loading kvm.ko module
Loading uinput.ko module
Loading parport.ko module
Loading dcdbas.ko module
Loading microcode.ko module
```

---

Answer (score 0):

The panic itself is actually quite accurate as is;

BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 0000000000000028
IP: [] free_async+0xa1/0x100

Tells already that the function where the problem happened is free_async and that function is exactly 0x100 bytes long and the crash happened at offset 0xa1. You need to map that offset into the exact line of code, but that now depends a bit on your environment how to do it.

Sometimes manual code review already will show what line has pointer manipulations, so you can do it just by reviewing that function.

Then the next question is that, why do you have a NULL-pointer there?